[SOLVED ]Discord.py commands aren't responding

I am trying to make a Discord bot using discord.py.

I created two commands.

When I sent ?hello bot didn't respond.


Here's the code:
import discord
import asyncio
import ast
from discord.ext import commands
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
    
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'logged in baby {bot.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    if 'nigg' in message.content or 'wigg' in message.content:
        author = message.author
        guild = message.guild
        await author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Racist'))
        await message.delete()

@bot.command()
async def calculate(ctx, *, expression: str):
    await ctx.send(f'{expression} = {eval(expression)}')

@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    print('hi')
    await ctx.send('hello guys')

bot.run('token')

And yes – the bot was running while I typed that command.
I tried using @bot.command() and expected bot to respond but nothing happened.
I solved it by add await bot.process_commands(message), you're welcome.

Welcome on StackOverflow! What version of discord.py are you using? Is anything getting printed in the console which you might share with us? If you add a print statement at the top of on_message, is anything getting printed to the console? Does anything happen if you mention the bot ("@yourbot hello") instead of typing "?hello"?

No I just type ?hello

I've did it by adding await bot.process_commands(message)

Please add your solution as an answer to your own question (and mark it as correct) instead of adding it to the question itself.

I found that adding await bot.process_commands(message) in the on_message() worked.
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    if 'nigg' in message.content or 'wigg' in message.content:
        author = message.author
        guild = message.guild
        await author.add_roles(discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='Racist'))
        await message.delete()

It will check if there are comments in that message.

You are correctly enabling the message content intent in your code, but is it also enabled in the developers web interface?
You can find this setting in the developer portal under applications => (your application) => Bot => Message Content Intent

Please note that the message content intent requires verification if you want to add your bot to more than 100 servers.
An alternative would be to use the newer app commands (slash commands).
Also note that using eval() with user provided input is a security risk as users might be able to run code on your device or the server hosting the bot.

I enabled it but when I delete the on_message event then it worked.

So you use ast.literal_eval() to do it right?

This would be better, but please note the warning: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

I found that sympy is better.
